# Run Rake task programmatically with specified environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm setting up a second database with my Ruby on Rails (3) application, so I want to create a rake task to create the second development database. I'm trying to overwrite the `rake db:create` task such that it does all the database creation that I need. However, it seems I can't find a suitable way to perform this task. I've tried a few approaches - establishing a connection to the database from the URL:

```rb
# remove db:create from the list of rake tasks in order to override it
db_create = Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:create')

namespace :db do
  task :create do
    if Rails.env == "development"
      # database.yml contains an entry for secondary_development, this works, as confirmed from rails console
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "postgresql://localhost/secondary_development"       
      Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke # this does nothing
    end

    # invoke original db_create task - this works
    db_create.invoke
  end
end
```

Another approach was to do:

```rb
# remove db:create from the list of rake tasks in order to override it
db_create = Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:create')

namespace :db do
  task :create do
    if Rails.env == "development"
      Rails.env = "secondary_development"
      Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
    end

    # invoke original db_create task - this doesn't work like this
    db_create.invoke
  end
end
```

This time *only* the `secondary_development` `db:create` works and the database is created as desired, but the `development` database is no longer created using this approach.

From one answer I found elsewhere, I thought that reenabling the task would be necessary, but that didn't change anything here and appears not to be the issue.

Finally, an approach that has worked is:

```rb
# remove db:create from the list of rake tasks in order to override it
db_create = Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:create')

namespace :db do
  task :create do
    if Rails.env == "development"
      system("rake db:create RAILS_ENV=secondary_development")
    end

    db_create.invoke
  end
end
```

The only issue here is that because the rake task is being run via `system`, the Rails application has to load before being executed, so I'm essentially loading the application twice fully just to run the task - this will be 3 times when I add a test database into the mix.

So, the actual question(s):

Is it possible to run `Rake::Task["..."]` programmatically with a specified environment?

Why doesn't `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` work in this way when creating the database? I had success when running this from Rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this. I believe the reason is that `.invoke` will not *always* invoke the task, but it will first determine whether it is necessary. Given that `rake db:create` is run on several occasions within the same task, `.invoke` deems the subsequent invocations as unnecessary and therefore does not run them. For the desired behaviour, `.execute` should be used instead.

```rb
# remove db:create from the list of rake tasks in order to override it
db_create = Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:create')

namespace :db do
  task :create do
    if Rails.env == "development"
      Rails.env = "secondary_development"
      Rake::Task["db:create"].execute # execute rather than invoke
    end

    # Reset the Rails env to 'development', otherwise it remains as 'secondary_development', which is not what we want (or move this above the if)
    Rails.env = "development"
    db_create.execute
  end
end
```